# How make my shape manifold? Substract one face from another?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, vertices, faces

I'm quite new to Blender and I'm having difficulties with a geometry. You can see it here:

[image]

As you can see there are holes which I need to fill as I need this to be a manifold, solid shape.

I have managed to fill the holes by selecting similar and fill command but the result is this:

[image]

It creates two faces as if they were "concentric circles". For instance if I delete the largest face I end up with this:

[image]

But what I want is to have a face **only** between the "concentric circles". Is there an option to subtract faces? That way what I would like would be to subtract from the large face the smaller face.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > **Bridge Edge Loops**.

[image: bridge-edge-loops]